# Show that the sum $\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^k x^k (1-x)^{n-x}(-1)^k f(\frac{k}{n})$ tends to $0$ when $n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, approximation

For $f\in C[0,1]$ show that for all $x\in[0,1]$ $\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^k x^k (1-x)^{n-x}(-1)^k f(\frac{k}{n})\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$

I don´t have a idea of how start with the proof, for one hand since our sum is the Bernstein polynomial with a extra $(-1)^k$ I think that must be $0$ since the Bernstein polynomial is a approach of our $f$ and therefore when we take all the terms of the approximation the error must be $0$.

For the other hand I need how fix the problem of the extra term $(-1)^k$ I think that we Can use the absolute value of our sum and find that these limit are $0$ for conclude that our original sum tends to $0$ when $n\to \infty$.

And basically I don´t know how I should continue with a formal proof of this.

I belive that I should calculate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \sum_{k=0}^nC_n^k x^k (1-x)^{n-x}(-1)^k f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)$$ or find  $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^k x^k (1-x)^{n-x}(-1)^k f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right|<\varepsilon$$

*Attempt*
Consider only the index $k\equiv 0\pmod 2$ then we should have
$$\left| \sum_{k=0}^nC_n^{2k} x^{2k} (1-x)^{n-x} f\left(\frac{2k}{n}\right)\right|\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left|f\left( \frac{2k}{n}\right) \right|C_{n}^{2k}x^{2k}(1-x)^{n-2k}$$
since the right sumand is at most $1$ then
$$\left| \sum_{k=0}^nC_n^{2k} x^{2k} (1-x)^{n-x} f\left(\frac{2k}{n}\right)\right|\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left|f\left( \frac{2k}{n}\right) \right|$$ but when $n\to \infty$ $\frac{2k}{n}\to 0$ and hence since $f(0)=p_n(1)=0$
$$\left| \sum_{k=0}^nC_n^{2k} x^{2k} (1-x)^{n-x} f\left(\frac{2k}{n}\right)\right|\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left|f\left( \frac{2k}{n}\right) \right|=0$$
Finally the case when $k\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ is analogous.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to separate terms with $k$ even and odd, and try to prove that both converge toward $\pm f(x)$.

Comment: In it case we should have two sums one with $\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^k x^k (1-x)^{n-x} f(\frac{k}{n})$  and the other $-\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^k x^k (1-x)^{n-x} f(\frac{k}{n})$ but the problem that i see with this is how index the $k$ in the sum now

Comment: One sum will index over $k$ such that $ 0 \leq 2 k \leq n$, the other over $0 \leq 2 k +1 \leq n$.

Comment: Thanks, I´m gonna try do it

Comment: I don't understand your attempt. Why do you say $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left|f\left( \frac{2k}{n}\right) \right|=0$?

Comment: I think the signs are crucial here.  If you put absolute values everywhere it will not converge to $0$.  So just using the triangle inequality won't get you anywhere. You have to make the positive and negative summands cancel each other out.

Comment: I would try to use uniform continuity of $f$.  If $f$ is constant the sum is $0$ or converges to $0$ because the positives and negatives cancel. Divide the interval into small segments and show that $f$ is close enough to constant on each segment that the sum over summands with $k/n$ in that segment is small.

Comment: Then I must expand the expression and center my mind in the summands  and watch which of them cancel to each other,for finally  use the uniform convergence? or I misunderstood the central idea

Comment: My idea is to get some bounds on each piece $\sum_{m\delta \leq k/n \leq (m+1) \delta} C_n^k x^k (1-x)^{n-x}(-1)^k f(\frac{k}{n})$ where $\delta$ is chosen so that $f(x)$ only varies by $\epsilon$ within $[m\delta, (m+1)\delta]$.  (I haven't worked this out though so I'm not sure if it will work.)

Comment: I thinik that it can works, since I see a similar argue here https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~kadison/bernstein.pdf